# Pseudo 3D walls (top-down raycasting, sort of)

Tags: c, 2d, parallax, allegro

See, I'm not posting code because I need logic, math, algorithms. Well:

I'm trying to achieve a 3d-looking visual for a top-down tile map using layers and parallax scrolling. The thing is: At the moment I simply set different "speeds" for each layer. But that would only work with some very specific camera positions, also, it makes so that the blocks have virtually an infinite height (as they will "increase in height" until they are out of the camera's FOV).

Is there a better (should be) to achieve the effect? Oh, and I'm using **C** with **Allegro 5**.

I thought about limiting each layer's offset, but I have no idea how.

**My current method:**

That's my current code for the layer "speed" (it repeats for up, down, left and right, changing coordinates):

```
if (key[ALLEGRO_KEY_UP])
    camera_y[0] -= 1;
    camera_y[1] -= 2;
    camera_y[2] -= 3;
```

Then I run a loop to draw the map with the tiles relative to the current layer's offset.

By the way, that's the desired effect (example with 3 layers):

[image: Effect]

Comment: Each layer should be scaled by the relative scrolling speed. Alternatively, you can draw 1:1 -sized overlay tiles on top of your background tiles relative to the viewport origin. For best results, construct the walls using cubic "boxes", with one flat top and four side tiles, two of which will be drawn skewed based on the location of the wall "box" relative to the center of the viewport.

Comment: I can't find anything related to this technique anywhere. I know that I can have it smoother and working alright, I just don't know exactly where to start from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For parallax scrolling, layers that scroll faster must be correspondingly larger:

[image: Scaled]

You can use unscaled tiles stacked on top of each other, offset by a fixed fraction of the distance from the center of the tile to the center of the viewport,

[image: Unscaled]

but the tops will not be continuous (unless the bottoms overlap). If all layer tiles are hand-drawn or rendered images, this is not an issue.

If the walls are box-shaped, and you have images of the top and each of the four sides, you can draw them in almost 3D,

[image: Walled]

where at most two sides of each box wall is drawn, skewed.

In all cases:

If the center of the viewport is at world coordinates (x<sub>c</sub>, y<sub>c</sub>), point (x, y, z) maps to coordinates (x', y') relative to the center of the viewport:

x' = (x - x<sub>c</sub>) × (z + z<sub>0</sub>) / z<sub>0</sub>

y' = (y - y<sub>c</sub>) × (z + z<sub>0</sub>) / z<sub>0</sub>

where z<sub>0</sub> is a constant that determines the "size" of the parallax or depth effect.

Comment: That worked pretty well, except for that the blocks are so close to each other, now. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/hNXmGdv.png)

Comment: @WilliamFernandes: Change z₀, or scale the source coordinates. Note that x,y,z are in same units as viewport coordinates (pixels).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right lines, but the "infinite height" issue can be solved by simply giving the camera an "altitude" property, and adjust the "speed" of each layer by calculating ...

layer.speed = (layer.altitude / camera.altitude) * ZOOM_FACTOR; //gives a float value.

Can't really suggest anything more until you show us some of your math code.

Comment: The player is in the camera's center, so the camera only moves when he moves. The "speed" thing is that I have 3 layers which increase and decrease on their X/Y coords by different values (Layer #0 increases by 1, while Layer #1 increases by 2 and Layer #2 by 3). I didn't quite understand how to apply that on my method.

Comment: Just added it, Wossname!